# cloud function update oracle onprem db for large volume of data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, serverless

Our application has the usecase to upload 20TB of files in GCP bucket.
Once its uploaded to GCP bucket, the corresponding bucket path should be updated to a onprem oracle db.
will the GCP cloud function or GCP pub sub will support this volume of data ?

Need some solution to update the GCP path in oracle on prem db for large volume of data

Answer (score 0):

A such volume of data can't be handle in a single piece by Cloud Functions (max 32Gb of memory) or PubSub (max 10Mb per message).

But Cloud Functions/PubSub can be use has orchestrator/notifier

- Your application create a 20Tb file in Cloud Storage
- Cloud Functions is invoked on the Finalized event on Cloud Storage
- The cloud function create a PubSub message
- You have a OnPrem environment that pull the PubSub subscription (push is also possible, but often more complex with your sec team) and when a message is detected, the 20Tb file downloaded locally (you can imagine that the Cloud Functions create a signed URL and put it in the message to allow your OnPrem environment downloading the file without authentication), and then load it on Oracle.

Comment: Thanks. Need a solution to update the bucket path (eg: google.com/bucket1/0/testfile.txt) in oracle db which in onprem when a file is arrived

Comment: The size of each file is 15Mb . our application db has totally 20tb (db size) size and each file has around 15MB size

Comment: Can you precise the context? Do you want to load the 15Mb file in Oracle from a Cloud Functions for instance? If so, is there order or concurrency constraint? Network bandwidth with your onprem?